# sms.db is not the iphone's sms storeage place?

Tags: ios, iphone, sms, jailbreak

I want to read all my iphone's sms messages through reading sms.db in my jailbreak device , and when i locate the sms.db , it seems like the sms.db 's modifytime(the last column in the picture) is not changed since the jailbreak(my device is jailbreaked in 2017-02-13,and i send some messages to it in 2017-03-05) , and every time the sms received ,just the sms.db-shm and sms.db.wal's modify time changed. so sms.db is not the place to read all the messages? so where is the place to read all the sms messages?
[image]

Comment: Yes, it _is_ the place where all SMS are stored, regardless of modification time - that's just a property that can be set at will anyway.

Answer (score 0):

OK,finally ,i got that ,sms.db is the storage of all the messages. the .shm and the .wal is the temporary file of sqlite3.7 introduce , and in fact we need put all these 3 files together to read the db